# Fetching number of Contacts from android contact app

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to fetch number of contacts from contact list. I follow the links of Stack Overflow and make a project. But it is not working.

The MainActivity.java is as follows:

```
package com.example.shiza.countcontacts;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
    public void GetTheContact()
    {
        Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        CharSequence text = "Total number is" + count;
//               int count = 1;
        Toast.makeText(this,text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am novice in Android. Please help me.

The manifest.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.shiza.countcontacts" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the phone number or just the number of contacts in you phone ?

Comment: Number of contacts only.

Comment: Use following library https://github.com/avirepo/AndroidPhoneContacts

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for you,

```
package com.example.shiza.countcontacts;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
    public void GetTheContact()
    {
        Cursor cursor =  getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToNext();

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        CharSequence text = "Total number is" + count;
//               int count = 1;
        Toast.makeText(this,text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to mention permission in you project manifest file,
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Answer (score 0):

First step, you have to declare the permission on AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Second, you have to access the contact list from you phone, and only after you may get the size of the list and the data from each contact.

This link will provide a example made by Google.
    http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

good luck.

Comment: I have included the above permission.

Comment: have you read the link and the sample from google? You just have to create an adapter with the data from you contacts and ask the size of the list.

Comment: I want to do the same. I think I am following wrong link. Please give me the link.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html (This will provide a list with all Contacts from you phone)